# REST wrapper for SOAP service with HATEOAS support

Tags: java, rest, soap, spring-hateoas

I did a REST wrapper for some SOAP services. Now I want to add HATEOAS support but, for the resources I use the auto created classes with the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` library. For example the auto generated class `BookDetails`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BookDetails", propOrder = {
     "id",
     "name",
     "title",
     "author"
})
public class BookDetails {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String id;>

  ...
}
```

I cannot extend that class from `ResourceSupport` because if the `.wsdl` change the `BookDetails` class is recreated and overwrite. Also if a created a new class that extends from `BookDetails` like `BookDetailsResource` then I cannot extend from `ResourceSupport`. Any idea or previous problem similar?

Here is a tutorial on how to create the wrapper if someone needs to implement it. https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-soap-client-webservicetemplate/

Comment: I already achieved it following this tutorial: https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/spring-hateoas-example/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create one domain model to map onto both, it's probably better to have separate domain models for SOAP and for HAL.

This way, you can use Spring Web Services deploy its contract-first approach and generate WSDL-based `BookDetails` domain objects.

From there you can define your REST controller and it's various methods to GET/POST/PUT, etc.

The final step would be to define a `ResourceAssembler<BookDetails, Resource<BookDetails>>` that leverages your REST controller, and ends up converting SOAP-based `BookDetails` objects into a HAL representation that includes relevant links.

Check out https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ to see how to structure the REST part of your app, and then think of the SOAP calls as being an underlying service layer your REST controller can invoke.